# How to find a function that describe the behavior of my data?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, function, math, exponential

I have some data I want to find a function that will describe my data.

[image]

This data looks like an exponential function:
I try to solve it according to this equation:

```
y = a*(b^t)
```

I use (1.75 ; 50) (3.25; 20)
and create 2 equation:

```
50 = a*(b^(7/4))
20 = a*(b^(13/4)
```

Solve it i receive following result:

```
y = (50/((0.4)^(7/6)))*(((2/5)^(2/3))^t)
```

But this solution not working and seems complex.
I am not so expert in math.

Is there any way to find an appropriate function that will describe my data?

I will appreciate any help

I also work in python, I was trying to find there a way to do it

Comment: Did you try `=LOGEST()` or `=LINEST()` function?

Comment: There is not a general idea for all sets of functions. You need to set an initial guess with some free parameters. Then try to optimize them somehow you will find the best fit for your data.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaBodego thank you for suggestion! It works for me